# Is it possible to configure Swagger to support implicit conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

According to the recommendations for restful services, do not recommend using complex data types in Get requests. The solution I found for myself was to create a custom Asp.Net IModelBinder that can parse a string into a complex type. As a result, I can create a Get method that receives a complex model as input.

However. The problem is that Swashbuckle generates documentation based on the method model. I can create an implicit conversion for a complex type. Is there any way to configure Swashbuckle so That it can generate documentation, allowing to pass a string instead of a complex model ?

For example. I have this type:

```cs
public class MyType
{
public int X {get;set;}
public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

I made a binder that can parse a string and create an object based on it.

```cs
public class MyTypeBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly IModelBinder _complexTypeModelBinder;

        public MyTypeBinder(IModelBinder complexTypeModelBinder)
        {
            _complexTypeModelBinder = complexTypeModelBinder;            
        }

        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            await _complexTypeModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);

            if (bindingContext.Result.IsModelSet)
            {
                var myValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("MyValue").FirstValue; // Taking the value from the get parameters

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myValue))
                {
                    bindingContext.Result.Model = new MyType (myValue);

                    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(bindingContext.Result.Model);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to suggest that my type should be serialized to a string.

```cs
            services
                .AddSwaggerGen(options =>
                {                    
                    options.MapType<MyValue>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" });
                })
                .AddSwaggerGenPatch();
```

However, after generating proxy class, I see the following:

```cs
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyRequestContent> GetSomeResultAsync(int? X, int? Y, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/MyTest/?");            

            if (X != null) 
            {
                urlBuilder_.Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString("MyValue.X") + "=").Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ConvertToString(X, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Append("&");
            }
            if (Y != null) 
            {
                urlBuilder_.Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString("MyValue.Y") + "=").Append(System.Uri.EscapeDataString(ConvertToString(X, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).Append("&");
            }


            var client_ = _httpClient;
            try
            {
...
```

**Can I somehow tell the generator how it needs to serialize my type ?**
The goal is to generate a proxy class that accepts the string "X_Y" as input and passes it to the controller, where the binder parses it. Now the proxy class accepts an object and passes it through the request parameters as a complex object "?MyValue.X=1&MyValue.Y=1".

Comment: Just to be clear the aim of all this is to go from `?X=1&Y=2` => `?MyValue=1_2` - I really don't understand the purpose.

Comment: The goal is to generate a proxy class that accepts the string "X_Y" as input and passes it to the controller, where the binder parses it. Now the proxy class accepts an object and passes it through the request parameters as a complex object "?MyValue.X=1&MyValue.Y=1".

Comment: I think you might need to leverage an `iDocumentFilter` to tweak the resulting schema

Comment: But this could be a bug on the new `OpenApiSchema`... I was searching and I've used a `MapType` successfully in the past:
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=Date#/Date/Date_Post
the code is here: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/commit/23862a06f3e19e1772ae87e92a2691f9803e65ff#diff-54396f15e910fddff9656d93fd03239dR137